# azure functions System.Text.RegularExpressions

Tags: azure-functions

I tried to replace some special characters in a text I want to use a slug link from an azure functions. Is it any way to use System.Text.RegularExpressions in an azure functions?

**Got this error:**
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.RegularExpressions, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace TestFunctionApi
{
    public static class Example
    {
        public static string CleanUpSlugText(string text)
        {
            text = Regex.Replace(text, "[áàäâãåáàäâãå]", "a");
            text = Regex.Replace(text, "[óòöôõóòöôõ]", "o");
            text = Regex.Replace(text, "[éèëêéèëê]", "e");
            text = Regex.Replace(text, "[úùüûúùüû]", "u");
            text = Regex.Replace(text, "[íìïîíìïî]", "i");
            text = Regex.Replace(text, "[^a-za-z0-9]", "-");
            text = text.ToLower();

            return text;
        }

        [FunctionName("Example")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [CosmosDB(
            databaseName: "database",
            containerName: "containerexample",
            Connection = "DBConnectionString",
            CreateIfNotExists = true,
            PartitionKey = "/Partexample"
            )]
            IAsyncCollector<ExampleClass> classExampledocumentOut,
            ILogger log)
        {
            var body = await req.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExampleClass>(body);
            request.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            request.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;


            request.Slug = CleanUpSlugText(request.Slug);
            await classExampledocumentOut.AddAsync(request);


            return new OkObjectResult(request);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How have you implemented the function? In the portal or compiled and deployed? Also, show us sample code if you can. Makes it easier to help.

Comment: Its compiled from visual studio 2022. It then I try a post request from postman I get the error, that my azure function cannot find the files for System.Text.RegularExpressions.

Comment: For this particular replacement task, ausing a `Regex` like this is going to be worse than just rebuilding a filtered string in a `foreach( Char c in ... )` with a `StringBuilder` and a giant `switch(c)` block.

Comment: As for the "Could not load file or assembly" error message: that suggests you didn't deploy your code correctly - please post your `.csproj` and `pubxml` files.

Comment: I see, I just updated my overflow post here with a code example. See the code example above. Trying to do some regex before I add the string to a sluglink from an azure function, when I try to create a cosmos database item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Got this error:** Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.RegularExpressions, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

- This error occurs if the Azure function is unable to locate to the correct version of the dependencies.
- And also, if the Azure functions SDK version and the package `System.Text.RegularExpressions` version is incompatible with each other.

To avoid this,

- Remove the existing version of the package if you have already installed. you can find all the installed dependencies along with its versions in `.csproj` file.
- Install the latest version of the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` dependency in your project.

[image]

```html
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.RegularExpressions" Version="4.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

*If that doesn't work, update the Azure functions sdk version.*

Comment: AH! Thanks for respond and advice. I will check this out asap.

Comment: Oh sorry for delayed response. Yes it worked well. Thanks a lot. We can set this post to solved.